# Error Ocurred while saving Snowpark DataFrame (Converted From Pandas DataFrame) using DataFrame.write.mode("append").save_as_table("TABLE1")

Tags: pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have read csv file using streamlit app using pandas DataFrame, the data is in Pandas DataFrame and the objective is to save this Pandas DataFrame into Snowflake Table.

There are Timestamp columns in csv file which are zero length value and are read by Pandas Dataframe as "nan" "Not a Number".

I converted this pandas dataframe to Snowpark DataFrame using method Session.create_dataframe( DF,schema); i ensured that i have provided schema too here.

Then i fired following command DataFrame.write.mode("append").save_as_table("TABLE1") I got the error as

"Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_TZ(9) but got NUMBER(38,0) for column RECORD_TS_CST"

I realized I should change data type of Timestamp column ,so I converted the Pandas DataFrame timestamp column to datetime64[ns] using

PdDF[col]= PdDF[col].astype('datetime64[ns]') i figured out that now the Pandas DataFrame Timestamp column value is converted to NaT(Not a Time) ;after that converted this pandas dataframe to Snowpark DataFrame using method Session.create_dataframe( DF,schema) and then fired method DataFrame.write.mode("append").save_as_table("TABLE1"), i am still getting the error as

"Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_TZ(9) but got NUMBER(38,0) for column RECORD_TS_CST"

I followed this article " [https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowpark-converts-Pandas-DateTime-type-to-LongType"](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowpark-converts-Pandas-DateTime-type-to-LongType%22) but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports using string constants to specify fixed date, time, or timestamp values. String constants must always be enclosed between delimiter characters.
So basically you need to change your datatype into string and this will work fine.

```
PdDF[col]= PdDF[col].astype('str')
```

For eg. when you are try inserting timestamp data into table in snowflake you pass it as string. So snowflake internally converts that into column's datatype i.e.timestamp